# Tab content with performance issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Im trying to making three tabs using ngfor and ngif.
Its actually working but with a performance issue
Look at the code

```
<mat-nav-list class="op-content">
  <h5>Listar Usuários</h5>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Filtrar por nome" class="filter-input">
  <mat-tab-group>

    <mat-tab label="Todos" [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="todos" ngDefaultControl>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let op of tboperadores | filter : searchText">
        <mat-list-item>
          <a matLine [routerLink]="['/operadores', op.id_operador]">
            <span class="badge badge-primary"> {{op.id_operador}}</span>
            Nome: {{ op.nome }} CPF: {{ op.identificacao }}</a>
        </mat-list-item>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Habilitados" [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="habilitado" ngDefaultControl>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let op of tboperadores | filter : searchText">
        <ng-container *ngIf="op.habilitado =='S'">
          <mat-list-item>
            <a matLine [routerLink]="['/operadores', op.id_operador]">
              <span class="badge badge-primary"> {{op.id_operador}}</span>
              Nome: {{ op.nome }} CPF: {{ op.identificacao }}</a>
          </mat-list-item>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Desabilitados" [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="desabilitado" ngDefaultControl>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let op of tboperadores | filter : searchText">
        <ng-container *ngIf="op.habilitado=='N'">
          <mat-list-item>
            <a matLine [routerLink]="['/operadores', op.id_operador]">
              <span class="badge badge-primary"> {{op.id_operador}}</span>
              Nome: {{ op.nome }} CPF: {{ op.identificacao }}</a>
          </mat-list-item>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-nav-list>
<div class="loader" *ngIf="!subscription?.closed" #loading>
</div>
```

As you can see, i have a ngfor for everytime i open a new tab.
I've tried to put just one for for the entire page, 
but I could not make it work.

Someone have an ideia how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

My operador.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { Operador } from './operador';
import { OperadorService } from './operador.service';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-operador',
  templateUrl: './operador.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operador.component.css']
})
//export class OperadorComponent implements OnInit, PipeTransform {
export class OperadorComponent implements OnInit {
  tboperadores: Operador[];
  checkedOperadors: Operador[];

  subscription: Subscription;
  mode = 'indeterminate';

  constructor(private operadorService: OperadorService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.getOperadores();
  }

  getOperadores() {

    return this.operadorService.getOperadores()
      .subscribe(ob => {
        console.log(ob);
        this.tboperadores = ob;
      });

  }
}
```

And, my filter.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.nome.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

- my operador.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Operador } from './operador';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OperadorService {
  private operadoresUrl = '******';  // URL to web api
  constructor( 
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getOperadores (): Observable<Operador[]> {
    return this.http.get<Operador[]>(this.operadoresUrl)
  }

  getOperador(id_operador: number): Observable<Operador> {
    const url = `${this.operadoresUrl}/${id_operador}`;
    return this.http.get<Operador>(url);
  }

  addOperador (operador: Operador): Observable<Operador> {
    return this.http.post<Operador>(this.operadoresUrl, operador, httpOptions);
  }

  deleteOperador (operador: Operador | number): Observable<Operador> {
    const id_operador = typeof operador === 'number' ? operador : operador.id_operador;
    const url = `${this.operadoresUrl}/${id_operador}`;

    return this.http.delete<Operador>(url, httpOptions);
  }

  updateOperador (operador: Operador): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.operadoresUrl, operador, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Ive edited this method to do the filter:

```
  getOperadores(option): Observable<Operador[]> {
    if (option == 0) {
      return this.http.get<Operador[]>(this.operadoresUrl)
    } else if (option == 1) {
      return this.http.get<Operador[]>(this.operadoresUrl).pipe(
        map((reports: Operador[]) => reports.filter(p => p.habilitado === "S"))
      );
    } else {
      return this.http.get<Operador[]>(this.operadoresUrl).pipe(
        map((reports: Operador[]) => reports.filter(p => p.habilitado === "N"))
      );

    }
  }
```

and created this two methods to call in the constructor:

```
  checkedOperadores() {

    return this.operadorService.getOperadores(1)   
    .subscribe(  ob  =>  {
       console.log(ob);
       this.checkedOperadors = ob;
      });

  }

  uncheckedOperadores() {

    return this.operadorService.getOperadores(2)   
    .subscribe(  ob  =>  {
       console.log(ob);
       this.uncheckedOperadors = ob;
      });

  }
```

But the performance issue continues...

Comment: why you repeating [(ngModel)]="searchText" on each tab ? I never worked with Angular Material, but it seams weird for me

Comment: I have updated my answer below, can you add the code of your filter pipe ?

Comment: Ive updated with my classes, thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried the lazy loading ?

Comment: Yes, but use lazy loading to load the pages separately dont solve my problem. I want to see the content of the tabs faster... The page load is not a problem.

Comment: how much elements you have ?

Comment: 2000 elements in the Json, each element have 23 columns. I think the problem could be when im rendering the tabs

Comment: Do you have the same perf as https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tab-content-perf-enhanced. I have 2000 elements and I found the result acceptable. I made same changes that i can explain if the result suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your time... the performance is very similar to my application, I'll look for some improvement, if I found one, i put that here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, you can use lazy loading to enhance the initialization phase:

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

> Lazy Loading
>   By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly
>   loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them
>   into the DOM until the tab is activated.
>
> If the tab contains several complex child components or the tab's
>   contents rely on DOM calculations during initialization, it is advised
>   to lazy load the tab's content.
>
> Tab contents can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a ng-template
>   with the matTabContent attribute.

If you still have the performance issue, you have to figure out how to use virtual scroll on your for loops.

**UPDATE**:
I don't know how your filter pipe is implemented, but you have to pay attention wheither it's a pure or an impure one. related to https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe it can make a performance issues.

You can improve your code too :

1 - Create three get methods, each for a kind of `habilitado` like :

```js
get habilitados() {
   return tboperadores.filter(op => op.habilitado === 'S')
}
```

then you use it in ngFor and get ride of the ngIf.

2 - Maybe create a component for the code below to reduce code lines :

```
<mat-list-item>
   <a matLine [routerLink]="['/operadores', op.id_operador]">
      <span class="badge badge-primary"> {{op.id_operador}}</span>
        Nome: {{ op.nome }} CPF: {{ op.identificacao }}
   </a>
</mat-list-item>
```